# Template specification get 'Ambiguous call to overloaded function'

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a template function that could return a `Collection` or the first element in `Collection`, which stored some native pointers.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Collection
{
public:
    std::vector<T*> m_Container;
};

template<typename T>
T* GetGlobal()
{
    return &(*g_GlobalStrings.begin());
}

template<typename T>
Collection<T>* GetGlobal()
{
    auto res = std::vector<T*>(g_GlobalStrings.size());
    for (auto&& item : g_GlobalStrings)
    {
        res.push_back(&item);
    }
    return Collection<T>{res};
}
```

But compiler(MSVC) says:

```
error C2668: 'GetGlobal': ambiguous call to overloaded function.
```

I'm not sure how to implement this. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: which one do you expect to be called for `GetGlobal<int>()`? Do you understand why it is ambiguous?

Comment: Simpler seems to have different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Return type doesn't make difference on function signature so</strike> the call is ambigious.

You should use something like std::enable_if<>.

The only way to prevent ambiguity is that not enabling both functions for the same type. Another simpler way is to change the function names.

Comment: return type make different signature for template function. We can call it in unambiguous way (but that is ugly).

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: I wasn't know that. Does the cast make possible to call ?  Or is it special for the template functions ?

Comment: template can differ only by return types. cast allows to select the overload

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.